# JOIN or nested SELECT in a WHERE clause to filter by a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table type, let's call it ListType which has 1 col - String VARCHAR(50).

I have a local variable of type ListType

This is populated with some string values - E.g. 'foo', 'bah', 'something', 'else'

I now want to use this table type as a param in a stored proc to filter the results from Table that will be returned.

There are ways I can think of doing this -

1 - JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM Table A
INNER JOIN @list B ON A.Col= B.String
```

2 - IN + (SELECT) in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table A
WHERE A.Col IN (SELECT [String] FROM @list)
```

I want to think that #1 would be more optimized than #2 but the query plan appears to be quite similar.

The underlying table has about 85M rows, the list will have at most 5 items in it.
Is there much difference?

Comment: Use the estimated times.  If the plans look similar and the plan estimates are the same, then they are probably compiling to the same execution plan.

Comment: interestingly when i had 1 list filter, the 2 approaches were almost the same. add another list and repeat this process and suddenly #1 is way quicker than #2. 

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff mentioned, seeing execution plan will correctly tell, what is happening.

Still, I would suggest you to go for OPTION #1, as it conveys SET based operations. If the list items are unique, I would also suggest you add index to the 1 col and it can bring added benefit.

[Using Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Table-valued parameters perform equally well or better than an
> equivalent parameter array implementation

```sql
CREATE TYPE ListType AS TABLE
(
Col1 STRING NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
)
```

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/ever-worth-adding-indexes-table-variables/